# PHP Creating two directories with same name at exact same time using mkdir

Tags: php, directory, mkdir

pls take a look at following code

```
 $directory_name = "directory_no"; 
 for($i=2; file_exists($directory_name); $i++){
   $directory_name =  "directory_no".$i;
 }
 mkdir(directory_name, 0755, true);
```

I have a webpage where when the user clicks on a **button**, a unique directory in same parent folder (at the server) is created,

as you can see in the above code PHP checks if the directory with the same name already exists or not. if yes it keeps incrementing the number at the end of the directory name, so if a directory with the name "directory_no" already exists. it will check for a directory with name "directory_no2" and if "directory_no2" also exists it will check for "directory_no3"  and so on.... until it finds a directory name which doesn't exist already.

Now pls Assume, first two users click that button at the exact same time, and at the exact same time PHP checks if the directory with name "directory_no" exists (the directory doesn't exist for both users at that time) and PHP tries to create the directories at the exact same time, what would happen then? I think that would throw an error.

**So my question is**

With the above code, is there still any possibility that two user's directories clash with each other?

thanks!

Comment: This is called a "race condition" and is indeed a potential issue. I would advise have a subdirectory for each user, or otherwise integrate the user's ID into the directory name, to avoid such clashes. But even then it's not really safe against race conditions. You may be better off generating a unique ID and saving that ID somewhere.

Comment: hmm, so with that code, creating unique directories would not be very trustable, I thought PHP would handle it itself somehow, thanks i will use unique id or something to avoid that "race condition", many thanks :)) @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: @nik It's too bad that PHP.net didn't think about locking folders as they did for files http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php *heh*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner very interesting, i really didn't know about that as well, still i need to learn lots of things, thanks guys for helping me:)

Comment: Instead of using file_exists, just go ahead and try to mkdir the directory immediately. Check the return code for success, if it failed it probably means the directory already exists. AFAIK it's impossible for multiple mkdir() calls to return success, only at most one will ever win. Perhaps add some additional error checking in the case of mkdir failing so you don't end up with an infinite loop if it failed because of a full drive.

Comment: You're welcome @nik - Maybe using a database instead, or in conjunction with this could work better for you.

Comment: @faffaffaff, funkfortyniner,  Thanks, I have understood your point, hopefully, I can implement that, thanks!

Comment: `$directory_name = "directory_no"; 
 for($i=2; !mkdir(directory_name, 0755, true);  $i++){
   $directory_name =  "directory_no".$i;
 }`  @faffaffaff, Hey, following your idea, I made little change in my code, I will also add unique_ids with the name of directories, but it is already more reliable, Thanks to you!